# How to dynamically add in custom directive from other custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I've created a directive that has similar functionality to datatables, but it's been customized for our app. One thing I have in my directive scope is `columnDefinitions`. Each object in that array has a property called `data`. I've got it set up so that if it is set to a string, it looks for that property on the entity, and it's a function, it will call that function with the entity. So basically this:

```
scope.getEntityData = function(entity, currColumnDefinitionData) {
            var entityData = null;
            if (angular.isString(currColumnDefinitionData))
            {
                entityData = entity[currColumnDefinitionData];
            }
            else if(angular.isFunction(currColumnDefinitionData))
            {
                entityData = currColumnDefinitionData(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                $log.error("Column defintion data property must be a string or a function. Cannot get entity data.");
            }
            return entityData;
        };
```

And then in my directive template, something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="currEntity in entities">
    <td ng-repeat="currColDef in columnDefinitions">
        {{getEntityData(currEntity, currColDef.data)}}
    </td>   
</tr>
```

This works great when I just need to output a string. I now have a case where I want it to insert a directive for the data in that column. I first just had the data property equal the HTML string. For example:

```
data: function(entity) {
        return '<div my-directive></div>';
    },
```

However, that resulted in the string just being inserted into the table cell (Angular escaping the text for me)

What I'm wanting to know, is how I can set up my directive so that I can get compiled directives into my table cells. I thought about having some way of telling myself it was a directive, and then compiling it with the `$compile` service, but then I don't know what to return from my function for it all to work right. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it

The directive:

```
angular.module('ui.directives').directive('uiCompile',
    [ '$compile', function(compile) {
      return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          var html = scope.$eval('[' + attrs['uiCompile'] + ']')[0];

          elem.html(html);
          compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
      }
    } ]);
```

The template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="currEntity in entities">
    <td ng-repeat="currColDef in columnDefinitions" ui-compile="currColDef"></td>   
</tr>
```

Basically for each column definition compile the content as a template using the current scope.

Comment: After thinking about some more, this is basically what I came up with. I'm glad to know I wasn't completely off base. Thanks for the answer.